# Meteor send email without authentification

Tags: email, meteor

I try to send an email from my METEOR server as described:
https://docs.meteor.com/api/email.html

But i want to send emails without authentication. I have no username and password. If i try MAIL_URL=smtp://@relay.xy.xxxxx.com:578 without username and password i get the error:

> unable to verify the first certificate.

Is it possible to set a parameter like "SMTPAuth=false" as in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the @ in the URL, that might help.

You are specifying port 578, which is a secure port, so it's probably trying to establish a TLS session with your server, which might not have a legitimate SSL certificate, which is likely to be causing this error message.

You know that if you have an email server that will accept unauthorised send requests, that a bot will find it, and then pour spam through it?

Comment: secure port is 587